# How to debug the script written in electron.js file

Tags: angular, electron

I have created an application using Electron(Angular4) , Spring boot and Mongo. I have written some script in Electron.js i.e. 1. Create some directories , 2. Open Mongod.exe 3.Run API jar and then up the Electron application.

I am facing some issue with my process flow. so need to debug it.

My question is  `how we can debug the script written in electron.js file ?`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug using the enable dev tool.

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { BrowserWindow } = electron;

let menubarWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        ...
})

// Show devtools menubar
//menubarWindow.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' })
```